# QGIS - Polygon to Lines Tool Incredibly Slow

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, mac, polyline-creation

I am trying to convert a few polygons to polylines so I can save them as a .GPX file.

I'm using QGIS 2.8.1 (Wein) on the Mac.

It seems to be hanging. I only have a few small polygons (see screenshot) but it's taking forever. I can't tell if it's actually processing them or if it's crashed. I usually give up after waiting 10-15 minutes.

Has anyone else run into this problem before?

Link to shapefile: https://ucdavis.box.com/shared/static/lhnqypkphlma4y1h4hw76gd29m8mdets.zip

[image: QGIS Polygons to Lines]

**EDIT:** I found a workaround by using GDAL ogr2ogr in the Terminal to directly convert the shapefile to a .gpx file. I used this command:

`ogr2ogr -f GPX -dsco GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=YES FPS_buildings.gpx FPS_buildings.shp -nlt MULTILINESTRING`

This is a good workaround but I still don't have an answer about my original question.

Comment: Can you share your source data as shp or GML or something?

Comment: Yes @user30184! Here is the shp: https://ucdavis.box.com/shared/static/lhnqypkphlma4y1h4hw76gd29m8mdets.zip

Comment: I don't have QGIS available but conversion with GDAL seemed to work `ogr2ogr -f gpx FPS_buildings.gpx FPS_buildings.shp -nlt linestring`. If direct output to GPX does not give a desired result you can use shp as an interim format. However, QGIS should really be able to do the job within a second as well.

Comment: Thanks @user30184, I will try the command line. I can't direct output to GPX because the shapefile has polygons, so QGIS throws an error. That's why I'm trying to convert to lines.

Comment: I meant direct output from polygon shp into gpx with my command, and that QGIS should be able to do the preliminary conversion from polygons into lines as you have tried. The attributes may not translate with ogr2ogr as you would like to.

Comment: I tried your     ogr2ogr command but I get this error:

    ERROR 6: Geometry type of `Polygon' not supported for 'rte' element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23672/discussion-between-mattsidor-and-user30184).

Comment: I got it to work with this command:

`ogr2ogr -f GPX -dsco GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=YES FPS_buildings.gpx FPS_buildings.shp -nlt MULTILINESTRING`

This is a good workaround but I still don't have an answer about my original question.

Comment: Not *sure* if it's the cause or not, but your shapefile has some issues. I ran a check geometry (ArcGIS) on it and found three of the records have null geometry. I suspect this is what's causing the tool to hang. I believe the equivalent check in QGIS is Check Geometry Validity. I also note there are two 'extra' polygons where three buildings overlap, which may or may not be intentional.

Comment: I tested this on QGIS 2.6.1 and @ChrisW is correct in that the _Check geometry validity_ tool does bring that errors. So you could try cleaning up your data with **v.clean**. An alternative to using GDAL is to use **SAGA: Polygons to Lines** as this worked without any problems and was done in a second.